# CSS Aligning a table

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a trouble aligning a table on the right side of an image. Both the image and the table are in a cell of a super table. Would you help me, please?

http://jsfiddle.net/QLYv7/

```
<td class="menu-section" style="background: #F0F;"> <a href="#">
    <img class="menu-section-icon" onmouseover="document.getElementById('menu-section-desc-0').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('menu-section-desc-0').style.display = 'none';" onclick="document.getElementById('menu-section-sub-0').style.display = 'block';" src="/resources/images/server-icon-breakpoint-web-64.png">
    <div id="menu-section-desc-0" class="menu-section-desc" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255); display: none;">
        <span class="menu-section-desc-content">
            Description stuff
        </span>
    </div>
</a>
    <div id="menu-section-sub-0" class="menu-section-sub">
        <table class="menu-table">
            ... table contents ...
        </table>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: That looks very much like it shouldn't involve tables in the first place.

Comment: Tables are a lazy person's layout tool. The rest of use use CSS.

Comment: Please describe what is happening vs what you would like to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make 2 boxes. one will contain the image and the other will contain the other 2 tables that you want to allign. then allign the 2 boxes with floating left and right

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I put together a structure with divs that might help you.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/QLYv7/1/)

HTML

```
<div class='leftone'>
    <div class='littletop'></div>  
    <div class='holderdiv'>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
          <div class='clearboth'></div>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='rightone'>
    <div class='littletop'></div>  
    <div class='holderdiv'>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
          <div class='clearboth'></div>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
        <div class='mediumdiv'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using divs instead of tables. Thank you for your help.